Determine Branch Currents using Kirchoff's Laws

In the above circuit, using mesh analysis, was able to get the below three equations and then using Cramer's Law was able to determine the currents in the three mesh.  Could I get a check on the equations derived?


No, your equations are wrong. You have the "sign" error on equation two and three. In the second equation only I2 should be positive, and the eq three only I3 should be positive as well.

Made with Maple.
You should write your equations as this, Maple rewrite these while simplifying.

Made with microcap v12


Please see the below answer.You have some error in the sign as G36 suggested.

